# Adding elements to Arraylist of int arrays in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following class for arraylist with int array.

```
public class MyClass extends ArrayList<MyClass> {

public int[] numAsc = {};
public int[] numDsc = {};

public MyClass(int[] numAsc , int[] numDsc){
    this.numAsc = numAsc ;
    this.numDsc = numDsc;

}
}
```

When I am trying add elements to arraylist, I am just getting empty arrays.

```
ArrayList<MyClass> numberSeries = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
int[] orders  = {1,2,3};
int[] request = {3,2,1};
numberSeries.add(new MyClass(orders,request));

Log.d(TAG, "numberSeries: " + numberSeries);
```

> RESULT FROM LOGCAT: numberseries: [[]]

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're adding to `numberSeries_info` but printing `numberSeries`

Comment: And your MyClass class must NOT extend ArrayList. It's not an ArrayList.

Comment: @Eran sorry, that was typo.

Comment: @JBNizet Could be please explain little bit more ? Sorry, I am not that experienced with java, yet

Comment: Well, remove `extends ArrayList<MyClass>`. MyClass is a class that has two arrays. It's not a list of other MyClass objects. So it has absolutely no reason to extend ArrayList<MyClass>. You can put cars in a queue. But that doesn't mean that a car is a queue.

Comment: okie, I understand. I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider the following points:

1. `MyClass` does not need to extend `ArrayList`.
2. Use Generics to instantiate the concrete classes e.g. `List<MyClass> numberSeries = new ArrayList<MyClass>();`
3. Override the `toString()` method in `MyClass` so that it becomes easier for you to print it.

Given below is the complete program incorporating the above points:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass{

    public int[] numAsc = {};
    public int[] numDsc = {};

    public MyClass(int[] numAsc, int[] numDsc) {
        this.numAsc = numAsc;
        this.numDsc = numDsc;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "numAsc: "+Arrays.toString(numAsc)+", numDsc: "+Arrays.toString(numDsc);
    }
}

public class TestMyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> numberSeries = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
        int[] orders  = {1,2,3};
        int[] request = {3,2,1};    

        numberSeries.add(new MyClass(orders,request));

        System.out.println(numberSeries);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[numAsc: [1, 2, 3], numDsc: [3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you extend `ArrayList`. I think you are overthinking it, if you just want to build a list of `MyClass` it does not need to extend `ArrayList`

- Remove the extend,
- make a sensible `toString` method on your `MyClass` object so you can see the values in your arrays

```
class MyClass {

    public int[] numAsc;
    public int[] numDsc;

    public MyClass(int[] numAsc , int[] numDsc){
        this.numAsc = numAsc ;
        this.numDsc = numDsc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "numAsc: " + Arrays.toString(numAsc) + " | " +
                "numDsc: " +  Arrays.toString(numDsc);
    }
}
```

Then run your main, it outputs:

> numberSeries = [numAsc: [1, 2, 3] | numDsc: [3, 2, 1]]